# How to read the parameter from the url contains '#' instead of '?'

Tags: java, jsp, url

How to read access token from this url? When I try to read this by `request.getParameter()` method it returns null value

`http://localhost:8080/FirstPick/views/common/home.faces#access_token=xxxxxxxxxx&expires_in=4015`

Comment: the hash (after #) is not sent to server. you can send it using javascript (AJAX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides this,

Content after the hash (#) is only be used on the client side. If you require that information on the server, you can use a different separator with query-string using '?', or you can submit it via Ajax after the page has loaded by reading it on the client with JavaScript.

The part of the URI after the hash(#) is never sent to the server, reason is that the hash identifier was originally designed to point at references within the given web page and not to new resources on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cant read any parameter from querystring like this..
It must contain '?'.
Only the string that appears after '?' is called 'QueryString'.
and from 'QueryString' you can get the value.
And you menstion the url here, is not contain '?' so it doesnt have 'QueryString'.
and You cant use request.getParameter() method.

Answer (score 0):

On client side (i.e. from JavaScript) you can check window.location.hash to get hash. On server side, general answer is 'it is impossible' since hash is not sent in request to server.